# Common space for Windows Universal app and website (Edge)

Tags: javascript, xml, local-storage, uwp, microsoft-edge

This is a unique requirement where we have an Universal Windows App which saves some configuration (xml) file in the system storage (app storage). Now, when someone open our web site (web version of same windows app) in the same system, we want to read the xml through JavaScript and render content accordingly. I know accessing file through javascript from browser involves permission issues in reading file.

1. We have tried setting local storage and access through iframe posting - Failed.
2. Saving to xml file and then tried to read when someone opens the web site using javascript - Failed.

We have workarounds like save to cloud and read from there. Like save to azure blob storage or SharePoint list/library and then read from there. But, it is specific to user settings, we like to avoid the round-trips and authentication stuff if we saved to cloud.

Any ideas we can achieve or solve this to share the file/content between the browser and windows apps?

-Praveen.

Comment: As you gathered, this goes directly against the isolation principles. This is what WebServices are for, tie it to a User instead of to a Device.

Comment: You really don't want browsers having access to local xml files in this manner. Your best option is to have the user manually select the XML (through an `input` control), or retrieve the XML data from the server.

Comment: Thanks I understand that. Thanks for the responses. In future, hope there will be new architecture which will give option to share space between Windows app and browser.

Comment: I hope there won't be (not without a lot of security fences anyway). Try to think like a hacker: those passwords and banking info would suddenly get a lot closer.

Comment: But do have a look at [Sharing your local app data](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/)

Comment: Yes, thank you. But that is the sharing space between apps. Still browsers can't access it. I believe using localstorage or index db is an option. But, through web views, I am opening the web site and saving some data to local storage, and when I try to see the local storage if I browse through browser I never see the values there. Seems like web views or hosted apps may open the inprivate session or handles in different way. :(